OpenShift cluster
I need advise on building test Open Shift cluster using least hardware (rack space).
Looking on requirements here:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-security/1.10?topic=planning-hardware-requirements
and these storage types supported by OpenShift
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/storage/understanding-persistent-storage.html
I need 6 x Machines (3 x Masters, 3 x Workers).My current plan is as follow:

1 x Host for Master Nodes (RHEL VMs on Proxmox or Hyper-V)
1 x Host for Worker Nodes (RHEL VMs on Proxmox or Hyper-V)
1 x Small server ex. with True NAS and then persistent storage for OpenShift will be NFS

What is confusing for me and I need clarification is this EKS Storage from IBM requirements is for Master/Workers or only for Workers. If only workers need to access it (this is shared FS for them) then Can i somehow perform my setup without this TrueNas Server? So on Worker Host I will physically had ex. RAID10 that I somehow will be able to expose to all VMs?
As RH and MS licenses are already provided I'm looking here also only on other free solutions like Proxmox or TrueNas if needed. Backup is not an issue and consideration in this setup.
Separate hosts for masters and workers due having max 26 Cores double CPUs available.
Any advises?
